# BufferedReader skip questions on a test/quiz

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Alright, so I'm taking on this little personal project for my teacher (Not my Computer Science teacher) and I'm trying to make a test from a fairly large list of questions. So far I've been able to read in the first question, ask the answer, and tell if they're right or not. The only problem is, it repeats the same question over and over.

Sadly, I'm stumped as to how I can make the program check to see if the question has been answered or not. My initial thought was to take the line from the question file that says "QUESTION #", separate the number, parse it into an integer and somehow make the BufferedReader skip that question.

Here is the quizTest:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class quizTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/eclipse/WorkspaceCompTIA.ActualTests.220-802.v2012-11-05.by.Caitto.txt/"));

        String line, userAnswer;
        int i = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String questionNum = "";
        String question = "", choiceA = "", choiceB = "", choiceC = "", choiceD = "", answer = "";

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

            if(line.contains("?")){
                question = line;
            }

            if(line.contains("A.")){
                choiceA = line;
            }

            if(line.contains("B.")){
                choiceB = line;
            }

            if(line.contains("C.")){
                choiceC = line;
            }

            if(line.contains("D.")){
                choiceD = line;
            }

            if(line.contains("Correct Answer: ")){
                String[] a = line.split(": ");
                answer = a[1];
            }
        }




        while(i < 274){

            quizClass run = new quizClass(i, question, choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD, answer);

            System.out.print(questionNum);
            System.out.println(run.getQuestion());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(run.getChoiceA());
            System.out.println(run.getChoiceB());
            System.out.println(run.getChoiceC());
            System.out.println(run.getChoiceD());
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Your Answer: ");
            System.out.println();
            userAnswer = scan.next();

            if(userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(i == 274){
            reader.close();
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is quizClass:

```
public class quizClass {

    private String question, answer, choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD;
    private int questionNum;

    public quizClass(int questionNum, String question, String choiceA, String choiceB,              String choiceC, String choiceD, String answer){
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.choiceA = choiceA;
        this.choiceB = choiceB;
        this.choiceC = choiceC;
        this.choiceD = choiceD;
    }

    public String getQuestion(){
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer(){
        return answer;
    }

    public String getChoiceA(){
        return choiceA;
    }

    public String getChoiceB(){
        return choiceB;
    }

    public String getChoiceC(){
        return choiceC;
    }

    public String getChoiceD(){
        return choiceD;
    }

    public int getQuestionNum(){
        return questionNum;
    }


}
```

And finally here is the format of the question file:

http://puu.sh/5nJhS.png
[image]

EDIT:

So after fiddling around with it, I've managed to get it working now(I'm sure there are better ways to go about it, but this way works, so I'm happy :P):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuizTest {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    String question = "";
    String choiceA = "";
    String choiceB = "";
    String choiceC = "";
    String choiceD = "";
    String answer = "";
    String line;
    String userAnswer;
    int i = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = null;           

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/eclipse/Workspace/CompTIA.ActualTests.220-802.v2012-11-05.by.Caitto.txt/"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        QuizClass run = new QuizClass(i, question, choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD, answer);

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

            //Finds the question
            if(line.contains("?")){
                run.question = line;
                System.out.println(run.getQuestion() + "\n");
            }

            //Finds answer "A"
            if(line.contains("A.")){
                run.choiceA = line;
                System.out.println(run.getChoiceA());
            }

            //Finds answer "B"
            if(line.contains("B.")){
                run.choiceB = line;
                System.out.println(run.getChoiceB());
            }

            //Finds answer "C"
            if(line.contains("C.")){
                run.choiceC = line; 
                System.out.println(run.getChoiceC());
            }
            //Finds answer "D"
            if(line.contains("D.")){
                run.choiceD = line;
                System.out.println(run.getChoiceD() + "\n");
            }

            //Finds the correct answer for the question
            if(line.contains("Correct Answer: ")){
                String[] a = line.split(": ");
                answer = a[1];
                run.answer = answer;

                System.out.print("Your Answer: ");
                userAnswer = scan.next();

                    //Checks if the user's input matches the correct answer from the file
                    if(userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
                        System.out.println("Correct!\n");
                        i++;
                    } 

                    //Checks if the user's input doesn't match the correct answer from the file
                    else if (!userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                        System.out.println("Wrong, the correct answer was: " + run.getAnswer());
                        i++;
                    }

            }


        }

                if(i == 274){
                    reader.close();
                    scan.close();
                }
}
}
```

Comment: You mean you want the user to be able to resume where they left off if they quit the program and restart it?

Comment: `"so I'm taking on this little personal project for my teacher"` -- sorry, but this smells like a homework assignment no matter what you claim. Regarding your question  though, does the code even compile? Where is the `answer` variable used in quizTest declared? I don't see a declaration anywhere, and so the compiler should complain about this. Also, please follow Java naming conventions: class names should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: "Alright, so I'm taking on this little personal project for my teacher (Not my Computer Science teacher) and " - This was not at all necessary. Just describe the question.

Comment: That only reason I DID say that was because I knew everyone would say "it's a homework assignment" even though it isn't.

Comment: @user3011559 Can you clarify your question? The question I had in my first comment still stands.

Comment: Sorry, no not necessarily that, (I might once I get everything working and add a GUI) but I wasn't sure as to how to tell the bufferedreader that the question has already been answer and to skip over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading in the whole file in your initial while loop and writing over your variables. So, to simplify, the program will read the line

```
A. NETSTAT
```

and set choiceA to "A. NETSTAT". It will then continue looping until it sees

```
A. Windows XP
```

and then update choiceA to be "A. Windows XP".

In the end, it will be like your program only read the last question.

How should you solve this? My first thought would be to encode your questions in XML, from which you load a set of questions. This is a less clunky solution but requires a bit more infrastructure.

If you want to stay with your current set up, you should have two loops: one outer loop the runs until your reach EOF, and an inner that loops until the "Correct Answer" line.

Extra tips/comments:

- Add a toString() method QuizClass (note the standard Java naming scheme -- always captialize) like this:

  ```
  public toString() {
    System.out.print(questionNum);
    System.out.println(question);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(choiceA);
    System.out.println(choiceB);
    System.out.println(choiceC);
    System.out.println(choiceD);
    System.out.println();
  }
  ```

and then call it in main with

```
System.out.print(run);
```

- answer variable in your QuizClass class does nothing. You instead use another variable, userAnswer, in the main class. Why?
- What is 274? Don't use magic numbers that don't mean anything. There's probably a constant defined in the classes you are using that are more informative.

Comment: I disagree with the part about having `toString()` essentially render the UI view for the question. While it is certainly reasonable for this simple program, in a general case you'd want to keep view code separate; e.g. if a GUI is added to display checkboxes for each choice, `toString()` would not be helpful. Conceptually, it would make more sense to rename `QuizClass` to `QuizQuestion` and have `toString()` return the question text; or just have `toString()` return a one-liner useful for debugging.

Comment: 1+ to using toString for debugging. 1+ to the answer because it does make some good points.

Comment: I'll agree with you regarding `toString()` in a more complicated case, as you mention. I mentioned it only as by looking at the output was how I realized the uselessness of the answer variable in the class.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention 247 is the number of total questions in the file. Also, thanks for the explanations and tips.

Comment: @user3011559 What happens when that number changes? You have two places to change, which means at least one place to forget about. Add a constant to the class: `private static final int NUM_QUESTIONS = 274;`.

Answer (score 0):

I see, your answer variable is declared all the way to the right in a long line of multiple variable declarations -- please don't do that. Whitespace is cheap, and so use it (but don't over-use it and sacrifice readability) -- give each variable its own line.

As for your problem, you have two while loops, in one, you read in your data, but discard it, and in the second you try to use the data, but can't since it's already been discarded.

To solve this, you could do it using only one while loop, not two. And in that while loop, read in your question data and act on it, and then loop to the next. If you must use two loops, then you'll need to first fill an ArrayList of quizClass (`ArrayList<quizClass>`) while reading in from the file, and then in the second loop, use a `for` loop, not a `while` loop (since you'll know the size of the ArrayList), and use the quizClass objects held in the ArrayList second loop to ask your questino and get your answers.

Comment: Actually, I can believe that this isn't a CS homework assignment. My calculus teacher told me to make him a 3D Battleship with vectorial attacks for extra marks. I am not denying the fact that this is a homework assignment though (as stated in his question)

Comment: @JoshM: If I were a calculus prof and needed something like this, I wouldn't ask someone in CS101 to create it for me, that's for sure. I'd ask for a more advanced level programmer.

Comment: This answer has some good coding tips and style pointers, but doesn't really address the question (although the OP *is* too vague to get a specific answer, it at least has something to do with skipping previously answered questions).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would too, but that wasn't why he asked me to write it. I wasn't required to write it; it was completely optional. He just wanted to see if I was able to write it given a particular deadline because he took some computer science when he was in school and found it interesting. The purpose of it was for a learning experience. Also, I'm not seeing how the last line of your answer is relevant. (I'm not the down voter)

Comment: In high school we had a required course in Pascal. At the beginning of the semester, the teacher commissioned myself and one other student to write some software to manage his fantasy football league. We did, he passed us, and we spent the rest of the year sitting in the back row playing Quake and trying not to laugh at The Onion.

Comment: @JasonC Haha, that was like my high school computer science class (minus the productiveness). Everyone just pretty much played games and went on Imgur and Reddit.

Comment: I don't care much about down-votes (or up-votes) to be honest. You can't buy beer or pizza with these damn votes, and yes, I'm a curmudgeon, but gosh, this does smell like a CS assignment, and CS100 at that. And for what it's worth I also up-voted lealand's answer because it's a good one (although I agree that toString should be used for debugging, not for production). So there. :)

Comment: Upvotes and downvotes are more for the benefit of readers than the poster, at least that's what I get out of them. A reader with a similar question who does not know the answer could (theoretically) use the vote count to judge how seriously to take the answer.

Comment: @JasonC: yep, can't disagree with that.

Comment: I swear this isn't a homework assignment. Even if, we havn't gotten into arrays yet, I've somewhat tough myself.